# set value in a form or pass a value in a form using jquery or javascript or ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

i created a Google Form and list down all the ID in each input type, and then created a localhost with the same ID,

The first thing i want to do is to save the values into a localhost and pass the values in the Google Form or set the values into the corresponding ID or Name in each input type in a new tab, is there a way to do this using ajax or jquery?

my form looks like this

```
<form method="post" action"">
     <input type="text" name="FName">
     <input type="text" name="LName">
     <input type="Submit">
</form>

$post('https://docs.google.com/a/grabtaxi.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfjiuhFbURVavdNW82ofHG3gPpBUKkK2VATQQKmV-YKKrJ75Q/viewform'{FName:Fname,LName}function(){
window.open('https://docs.google.com/a/grabtaxi.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfjiuhFbURVavdNW82ofHG3gPpBUKkK2VATQQKmV-YKKrJ75Q/viewform');
});
```

i am trying to use the $.post() in jquery but it looks like i cannot set the values into the Google Form.

Any tips please... Thank You very much

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your javascript code inside a *scipt* tag. Then, you should bind the code to submit event, tha happened when you press the submit button.

```
<script type="JavaScript"> 
$('input[type=submit]').submit( 
    // here you should put your code
});
</script>
```

And check your code, you wrote *$post* instead of *$.post* mi sing the dot.